# Is there any command line tool that can create zip/rar archives of all the sub-directories if given a path to parent directory?

Tags: logging, zip, archive, command-line-tool

I have a bunch of sub-directories of daily log files generated by my web application. Ideally what I would like to achieve is if given a path to a parent directory *(i.e.)~/myapp/logs/july-logs/* the tool creates individual zip files of every single day sub-directory *(i.e.) 11.07.23-myapp-logs.zip, 12.07.23-myapp-logs.zip etc.* I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZqee.jpg) for better understanding of the directory structure.

I have tried multiple times to find a tool on the Internet and gone through Github to find a repo where someone has developed a similar solution but no LUCK. I just want someone who knows how this can be done to point me in the right direction. **I am ready to write a tool that can solve my problem from scratch and I posted a question here to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel.**

Answer (score 0):

tar -cvf backup.tar /path/to/backup

Comment: I used your command to create a .tar file however it just creates an archive of the entire directory does not create .tar files of the sub-directories. Screenshot for reference. Listing the contents tar -tvf backup.tar  https://imgur.com/a/j5Nnyyg

Comment: From your logs directory try this tar -cvf may-logs.tar ./may-logs && tar -cvf june-logs.tar ./june-logs && tar -cvf july-logs.tar ./july-logs && tar -cvf logs.tar *.tar && mv logs.tar ../logs.tar && rm *.tar. should be seperated logs now located within myapp directory.